# Hard time with getting OpenCV running in CLion on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, cmake, clion

Ive been trying to get my OpenCv to work with CLion on a Mac running BigSur

I believe i installed my OpenCv in the correct way, i used the steps outlined in: https://thecodinginterface.com/blog/opencv-cpp-vscode/

I want the code to display an image, the code itself looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp"

using namespace cv;

const char* image_name = "Madvillain";

int main() {

    std::string image_path = "/Users/user/Pictures/45053_madvillain.jpg";
    Mat src = imread(image_path);

    imshow(image_name,src);

    return 0;
}
```

My CMake file looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")

project(OpenCvTesting)

set(OpenCV_FOUND 1)
set(OpenCV_DIR /Users/user/OpenCV/install/lib/cmake/opencv4)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(OpenCvTesting main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(OpenCvTesting ${OPENCV_LIBS})
```

After linking OpenCV with my C++ Code i get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::Mat::~Mat()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think I linked my CMake file correctly since it recognizes that the function itself is from OpenCV, but the code itself just does not want to run. I have no clue what to do, I've been searching for similar problems but they don't involve CLion and once people link their file correctly with CMake it works for them.

Comment: The referenced tutorial uses following line for link with OpenCV: `target_link_libraries(simple-demo ${OpenCV_LIBS} )`. But your code uses `OPENCV_LIBS` variable. In CMake a variable name is **case-sensitive**.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, i was busy debugging for quite a while